# How To Perform Time Series Data Patterns Classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, time-series

I'm fairly new to Python, and I want to create a Machine Learning algorithm that classifies Time Series Data Patterns.

The data I will be using comes from an accelerometer-arduino system fashioned into a glove worn in the hands, which writes data on a csv file. I need it to be time series data patterns, so that I can record hand gestures that last about 4 seconds. For example, I want to record a hand wave for five seconds, or I want to record a hand drawing a circle in the air for four seconds.

Then when all is final, what I will be doing is use the machine learning code to classify the live data based on the models created, as they are being performed.
From what I've gathered, what I should do is create a training data by performing the gestures repeatedly. However, I am clueless where to go from there.
Upon the final product, my goals should be these:

1. Create machine learning scripts that would classify Time Series Data Patterns. Another specific concern is setting the interval of patterns into every 4 seconds.
2. Use the models or the prediction script to classify matches from live data written to a csv file with the ones created in the model

I don't know how to move forward after creating csv files. I don't understand what algorithm do I need to use, and how do I go about it.

So far, I've understood what models are and what preprocessing is, but I don't know where to go from there. I understand that the training models may be stored into pickle files for reference in the actual comparison, but I'm inexperienced regarding the machine learning algorithm itself.

Any advices and help would really be appreciated. Thank you.